# Compare System Date With Number Of Days From The Date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table as below

Table name payreg

```
+------+-----+------+
|  A   |  b  |  c   |
+------+-----+------+
| NULL | YES | NULL |
+------+-----+------+
```

I wants to check column if it is null than throw message error like “ A is Null”

I have try as below:

```
declare @bb varchar(100)
set @bb=(select a from payreg )
if @bb is null and day(getdate())>=3
begin
print 'sorry'
end
```

the above SQL Transact executed successfully but not print error message

I want to compare such column with system date if the current system date is greater or equal to days 3 then throw error “Sorry”.

But fail to get it. How to solve it?.

Comment: I don't think your example is at all clear. What does "if the current system date is greater or equal to days 3" mean? Are you meant to be comparing the current system date with some other date? If so, where does that other date come from?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever   I am not comparing system date to other date. I just compare system date with no of days e.g. 1 to 31. if current system date is greater than no of days 4 or 5 then throw error message like above.

Comment: If I create a table called `payreg`, insert a row that looks like the one you show, and then run your script, it prints `sorry` for me. So something is missing from your question but I have no idea what.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Sorry to say but it is really not works for me don't know why?.

Comment: in my case it is print the message like " command completed successfully".

Comment: Is there definitely only one row in `payreg`? Is `a` definitely `NULL` (and not, say, the string `'NULL'`)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It is sorry. The mistake from my side that I have change the records from table and forget to refresh it that's why it is not return the result as a coded. Thanks buddy for co-operation.

Comment: By the way, if you do want this to be an *error*, you might want to look into using [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) rather than `PRINT`, e.g. `RAISERROR('sorry',16,1)` will cause client tools (or even just management studio) to report it as an error.